# Recieve all posts by tag and get updates likes in realtime

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I programming some tools for company promo actions.

I need recieve all posts by hashtag and get updates likes in realtime.

For example get hashtag #nescaferussia2019.

1. Get all posts with this hashtag
2. I need get all updates by likes and new posts by tag in realtime.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As of today the Instagram Graph API does not support this, You can only get hashtag data for last 7 days using business account and graph API. (The old deprecated API was supporting all posts from hashtag and realtime update)